# how to convert buffer stream data from fingerprint capture to byte array in nodejs

Tags: node.js

How can i convert buffer data coming from fingerprint capture to byte array in nodejs

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrByte = Uint8Array.from(data)
```

Also, see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511307/nodejs-conversion-from-buffer-data-to-byte-array) and the [docs for Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray).