# nodejs conversion from buffer data to byte array

Tags: arrays, node.js, byte, typed-arrays

I want to convert buffer data to byte array. Here's what I've tried

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
[...]
event:(data) => {
   fs.readFile(data, function(err, data) {
      var arrByte= new Uint8Array(data)
      var binaryData= new Blob([arrByte])
      console.log(binaryData)
   }
 }
```

I'm yet to have this work hence my post. I'd very much like to know what I'm doing that's not right.

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: @Cerberus the output is blank not logging anything

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`Buffer` docs are very enlightening](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray):

> Prior to the introduction of `TypedArray`, the JavaScript language had no mechanism for reading or manipulating streams of binary data. The `Buffer` class was introduced as part of the Node.js API to enable interaction with octet streams in TCP streams, file system operations, and other contexts.
>
> With `TypedArray` now available, **the `Buffer` class implements the `Uint8Array`** API in a manner that is more optimized and suitable for Node.js.
>
> …
>
> **Buffer instances are also `Uint8Array` instances.** However, there are subtle incompatibilities with `TypedArray`. For example, while `ArrayBuffer#slice()` creates a copy of the slice, the implementation of `Buffer#slice()` creates a view over the existing `Buffer` without copying, making `Buffer#slice()` far more efficient.
>
> It is also possible to create new TypedArray instances from a Buffer with the following caveats:
>
> 1. The `Buffer` object's memory is copied to the `TypedArray`, not shared.
> 2. The `Buffer` object's memory is interpreted as an array of distinct elements, and not as a byte array of the target type. That is, `new Uint32Array(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3, 4]))` creates a 4-element `Uint32Array` with elements `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, not a `Uint32Array` with a single element `[0x1020304]` or `[0x4030201]`.

They go on to mention [`TypedArray.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from), which in node accepts `Buffer`s, so the 'correct' way is:

```
var arrByte = Uint8Array.from(data)
```

...however, this shouldn't be necessary at all since a `Buffer` is a `Uint8Array` and `new UintArray(someBuffer)` does work just fine.

There's also no context in your question, but `Blob` doesn't exist in node, and you shouldn't need it anyway, since `Buffer` already gives you raw access to binary data and the other `fs` methods let you read and write files.

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, logging arrByte gives this output `Uint8Array [  ]`

Comment: And what is your buffer (`data`)?  What is `err`?  I bet you're getting an error and ignoring it.  Never skip error checking -- ***always*** check `err` in node callbacks.

Comment: this is the buffer data from fingerprint renderer process `<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 01 f4 01 f4 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 ...>` which I want to convert to byte[] and I've also checked `if (err) throw err`... Guess there's no err

Comment: i was able to get `Uint8Array(55797) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 244, ...]` when i set arrByte to `Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(data))` Thanks a lot

Comment: @lilKing Hi, can you pls share the code here, because iam also having the same issue converting buffer data to byte array.

Comment: @MidhunKrishna I'll post it shortly. Hope it helps

Comment: There is an easier way to do this outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127012/11544830

Answer (score 9):

```
  import * as fs from 'fs';
  [...]
  event:(data) => {
    fs.readFile(data, function(err, data) {
      var arrByte= new Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(data))
      var binaryData= new Blob([arrByte])
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(binaryData)
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the type of "data" variable?

Comment: @VikasSatpute in the outer context (i.e. as the first parameter to fs.readFile) it's the file name; in the inner context it's the data read from the file. In my tests, the inner data is already of type Buffer so you don't need to call Buffer.from(data) at all.